# Ember 1.13 store.query always from cache in IE11

Tags: caching, ember.js, ember-data, internet-explorer-11

I upgraded my Ember web application from ember 1.12.2 to 1.13.13 with ember-cli 0.2.7 and ember-data v1.13.16. 
Now for some models the store.query('modelname', {'something': thus.get('id')} always gives old data in IE11. When I check the REST call in IE11 I also see 'from cache'. Why? In Chrome it does get the data from te server, NOT from the cache. 
How can I tell in my Ember code it must NEVER get the data from cache?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Well you could hack something together, but the right way to fix this is to specify the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header on the response.

The only way to solve this from the client is to add a unique id (like a timestamp) to every request so that every request seems unique. But why a hacky solution if the right path is clear?